# HTML basics / scrolling on front page to specify class

Tags: javascript, html

Im wondering how to make a "event" in js or whatever, that when im clicking in example "about us" in footer, it scrolling page up to "about us" section, with smoothly move.

Comment: Add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the "about us". Then use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) within the event to scroll to the about section.

Comment: rathern then using a class, you should give them an id and then use an anchor that links to the id: `<a href="#id">About Us</a>`. Then you can use smooth-scroll in the CSS: `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a class, you should give them an id and then use an anchor that links to the id: `<a href="#id">About Us</a>`. Then you can use smooth-scroll in the CSS: `html { scroll-behavior: smooth; }`

```css
html {
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

section {
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<section id="home">
  <a href="#aboutUs">Scroll to About Us</a>
</section>
<section id="aboutUs">About Us</section>
```

No need for JS

Comment: Much better than my idea in the comments :)